# Naming Context not found exception

Tags: ejb, websphere, jndi, ibm-rad

I am deploying a EAR from RAD .The EAR pacakges a WAR and EJB module. I am getting the following error after the application in invoked..

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: C7M91P-L93883NNode01Cell/nodes/C7M91P-L93883NNode01/servers/server1, name: ejb/org/ifc/dots/business/services/DOTSStartupServiceHome: First component in name DOTSStartupServiceHome not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4360)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1793)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1748)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1499)
```

How do I verify the naming context entries in the websphere server... ?

---

Actually the error occurred because the ejb was not part of the EAR deployment descriptor..I added ejb module in the deployment descriptor and now the error is gone..

I am now getting the following error..

> [2/6/14 18:16:37:808 IST] 00000023 FfdcProvider  I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\logs\ffdc\server1_295f295f_14.02.06_18.16.37.59110970.txt com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt 1507
>   [2/6/14 18:16:37:810 IST] 00000023 Helpers       W   NMSV0610I: A NamingException is being thrown from a javax.naming.Context implementation. Details follow:
>   Context implementation: com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl
>   Context method: lookupExt
>   Context name: C7M91P-L93883NNode01Cell/nodes/C7M91P-L93883NNode01/servers/server1
>   Target name: ejb/org/ifc/dots/business/services/DOTSStartupServiceHome
>   Other data: ""
>   Exception stack trace: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.InvalidObjectException: Some object reference in the name "ejb/org/ifc/dots/business/services/DOTSStartupServiceHome" relative to the context "C7M91P-L93883NNode01Cell/nodes/C7M91P-L93883NNode01/servers/server1" is invalid.  Some possible causes include a context binding in the name which refers to a destroyed context, or an object binding which contains an invalid EJBHome reference. [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.INV_OBJREF: Could not resolve IOR string.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapINV_OBJREF(CNContextImpl.java:4391)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1807)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1748)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1499)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:636)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>       at org.ifc.dots.business.locator.ServiceLocator.getServiceHome(ServiceLocator.java:228)
>       at org.ifc.dots.business.delegation.DotsBusinessServiceDelegate.invokeService(DotsBusinessServiceDelegate.java:96)
>       at org.ifc.dots.web.aggregation.DOTSXMLHelper.getXML(DOTSXMLHelper.java:468)
>       at org.ifc.dots.web.servlet.DOTSWebServlet.getXMLElement(DOTSWebServlet.java:126)
>       at org.ifc.framework.web.servlet.BaseWebServlet.service(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1449)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
>   Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INV_OBJREF: Could not resolve IOR string.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.resolveUnresolvedBinding(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1995)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.resolve_binding(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1675)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:580)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2163)
>       at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2792)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2788)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:762)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2786)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1789)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST: SERVANT_NOT_FOUND (4) for key 0x49454a50020033e2132d077365727665723103454a420000005cacac0002000100290000005f5f686f6d654f66486f6d6573235f5f686f6d654f66486f6d6573235f5f686f6d654f66486f6d657308444f5453494923444f54534949456a622e6a617223444f54535374617274757053657276696365  vmcid: IBM  minor code: C14  completed: No
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ObjectManager.lookupServant(ObjectManager.java:110)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.getServant(ServerDelegate.java:311)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.lookupLocalObject(ORB.java:592)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.lookupLocalObject(ORB.java:1465)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.newObjRef(CDRReader.java:1290)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_Object(CDRReader.java:1130)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_Object(CDRReader.java:1094)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.IorURL.iorbytesToObjref(IorURL.java:105)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.IorURL.resolve(IorURL.java:93)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.objectURLToObject(ORB.java:3718)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.objectURLToObject(ORB.java:3256)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.string_to_object(ORB.java:3619)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.resolveUnresolvedBinding(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1921)
>       ... 43 more

Comment: use dumpNameSpace.bat/.sh in the WAS_HOME/AppServer/bin directory to find out the contents of your remote directory. If you are seeing stack traces there, that means the directory might be corrupt. Have you deleted and recreated a server instance on that node before?